# How to sync textareas using react hooks?

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, react-hooks

I'm trying to sync two textareas when the checkbox is checked.

Here I used useState hook to control the checkbox and textareas but I think I'm missing the logic at the ternary operator, could anyone help in getting this right?

This is what I have tried to fix it but that doesn't work.

Here I used the variables ca for correspondence address and pa for permanent address

```
import React, {useState} from 'react' 

const Sync_address = () => {

const[pa, setPa] = useState('');
const changePa = e =>{
    setPa(e.target.value);
}

const[ca, setCa] = useState('');
const changeCa = e => {
   setCa(e.target.value);
}

const[checked, setChecked] = useState(true);
console.log(checked)
const handleChange = () => {
        setChecked(!checked)
        return setChecked ?  ca == pa : ca == ca
}


    return (
        <div id="sync-address" className="mx-auto container">
            <h2>Please enter the both the address</h2>
            <input type="checkbox"
            checked={checked}
            onChange={handleChange}
            />
            <span>sync address</span> 
            <br />
            <p>Permanent Address :</p>
            <textarea rows={5}
                      cols={50}
                      value={pa}
                      onChange={changePa}
            >
                      
            </textarea>
            <br />
            <p>Correspondance Address :</p>
            <textarea rows={5}
                      cols={50}
                      value={ca}
                      onChange={changeCa}
                      >
                        
            </textarea>
        </div>
    )

}


export default Sync_address
```

The warning I'm getting here is `Expected '===' and instead saw '=='`

I have tried to replace == with === but still the code works in same way.

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to do in this condition? `return setChecked ?  ca == pa : ca == ca`

Comment: @Tushar when setChecked is true then ca should be same as pa. And when it is false, ca should be different

Comment: perfect, just answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to just update values on checkbox checked, you need to tweak your `handleChange` function

```
const handleChange = () => {
       setChecked(!checked);
       setCa(checked ?  pa : ca );
}
```

Comment: Actually what I'm trying to do is, when checkbox is true, both the textareas should work like two-way binding. Is that possible?

Comment: What do you mean by two way binding? If check box is checked, both address would be same right?

Comment: Also when I run this code, you know by default the checkbox value is true and when I start typing in textarea, both of them are not working like two-way binding. Instead when I uncheck it, my correspondence and permanent address are getting filled with same value

Comment: by two-way binding I mean this... https://qph.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-62ef8a4846eab3460ab3e43ddc35f87d the moment I start typing in Permanent address then it should also be visible in correspondence address

Comment: Thank you. The changes I made are: 1) The correction which you said. 2) I made default check box as unchecked. and 3) I moved my checkbox down after the permanent address. Now I just have to disable the correspondence address textarea when syncked (checkbox checked), that I will try to figure out. And yes, as of now, it's not working as two way binding which I wanted but yet I'm satisfied for now. Finally, learned how to use a hook by this program :)

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to change `ca` state based on the changes that're happening to `checked` state. For this, you can have a `useEffect` to keep track on the changes that are happening to `checked` state and do the updates on `ca` as follows. In this case, I put `""`, if `checkBox` is unchecked.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const Sync_address = () => {
  const [pa, setPa] = useState("");
  const changePa = (e) => {
    setPa(e.target.value);
  };

  const [ca, setCa] = useState("");
  const changeCa = (e) => {
    setCa(e.target.value);
  };

  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);

  const handleChange = () => {
    console.log(checked);
    setChecked((prevState) => !prevState);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setCa(checked ? pa : "");
  }, [checked]);

  return (
    <div id="sync-address" className="mx-auto container">
      <h2>Please enter the both the address</h2>
      <input type="checkbox" checked={checked} onChange={handleChange} />
      <span>sync address</span>
      <br />
      <p>Permanent Address :</p>
      <textarea rows={5} cols={50} value={pa} onChange={changePa}></textarea>
      <br />
      <p>Correspondance Address :</p>
      <textarea rows={5} cols={50} value={ca} onChange={changeCa}></textarea>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Sync_address;
```

Hope this would solve your address sync issue.

Comment: Thank you. The useEffect hook is new for me. However, There is one more new thing I observed here is `[checked]`. what does that do?